# Is it allowed to include a space in Vim's 'iskeyword' option?

Tags: vim

The document of `'iskeyword'` doesn't mention this. I thought it's possible as `'isfname'` allows to include a space(although not recommended).

However, after `set iskeyword=@,48-57,_,32`, a space is still not recognized as a keyword character. Do I miss something?

Comment: I can't say if it's possible or not but doing this would break the functionnality of so many text-objects and motions that it sounds silly.

Comment: I agree with romainl, can you tell us why you might want to do that?

Comment: I was trying to set the option 'iskeyword' for a thesaurus file, which may contain a phrase that I want it to be a keyword. Otherwise I would only include words in it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible (but you should only do this temporarily, e.g. for thesaurus lookups, as such a setting is unexpected and bound to break many plugins and other things in Vim).

I'm able to include a space via

```
:set iskeyword+=32
```

Which results in `iskeyword=@,48-57,_,192-255,32`. I get the correct *hlsearch* highlighting and `matchstr(..., '\k\+')` matching.

Note that it is still quite difficult to get the *thesaurus completion* (`i_CTRL-X_CTRL-T`) to yield multiple words, because the completion base now also includes all (modified) keywords before the cursor, and that now can be multiple words, too!

Comment: I thought the option 'iskeyword' can be set from the 'modeline' of a thesaurus file. But changing the current buffer's 'iskeyword' option is certainly not suitable. Also, the motions like `w`/`b` never see a space as a keyword character. So I just give up, delightedly.

Comment: That modeline will only be considered if the thesaurus file is loaded for normal editing. If you want to use it for thesaurus completion, that goes through a different code path; it's not loaded as a Vim buffer, not even hidden in the background.

Comment: I have in fact implemented multi-word thesaurus completion, but it's so full of hacks that I haven't considered publishing it. Rather, I'd love to see this feature implemented in core Vim (which is unlikely with the current dev situation).

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. I'd also love to see this feature be perfected.